# Error C2065 with function pointer to static member class

Tags: c++, function, pointers, static

I'm trying to change an existing code of a static const struct in my header class used as a base for my db creation. The current code is

```
//database.h

#define VIDEODB_TYPE_INT 1
const struct DBHeaders
{
  std::string name;
  std::string dbType;
  int type;
} DBHeadersTable1[] = 
{
  { "idRow", "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY", VIDEODB_TYPE_INT},
  { "value", "INTEGER", VIDEODB_TYPE_INT}
};

const struct DBHeaders DBHeadersTable2[] = 
{
  { "idRow", "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY", VIDEODB_TYPE_INT},
  { "value", "INTEGER", VIDEODB_TYPE_INT}
};

class CDatabase
{
public:
  void getDatabaseInteger(DatabaseRow& details);
  void get(int column, DBHeaders headers, DatabaseRow& details)
  {
    if (headers[i].type == VIDEODB_TYPE_INT)
      getDatabaseInteger(details);
  }
  //other functions
}
```

But this method isn't great anymore because now we have fields that needs changes to be used. So instead of giving a number that represents the function I want to insert directly a pointer to the function allowing a lot more flexibility. This is my new code

```
//database.h

typedef void (*getFunctionType)(DatabaseRow&);
const struct DBHeaders
{
  std::string name;
  std::string dbType;
  getFunctionType getFunction;
} DBHeadersTable1[] = 
{
  { "idRow", "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY", &(CDatabase::getDatabaseInteger)},
  { "value", "INTEGER", &(CDatabase::getDatabaseInteger)}
};

const struct DBHeaders DBHeadersTable2[] = 
{
  { "idRow", "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY", &(CDatabase::getDatabaseInteger)},
  { "value", "INTEGER", &(CDatabase::getDatabaseInteger)}
};

class CDatabase
{
public:
  static void getDatabaseInteger(DatabaseRow& details);

  //other functions
}
```

The idea is that to have a defined const with my rows and a pointer to the function the code have to use to parse the column. The error i get is:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewcf0002.aspx
at line

```
  { "idRow", "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY", &(CDatabase::getDatabaseInteger)},
```

And between parenthesis of the error i don't have "database.h" but another file...
Is it possible to point a static function in this way? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The function type needs to declare a member function type to get this working: `typedef void (CDatabase::*getFunctionType)(DatabaseRow&);`. Also note you don't have this function declared as `static` member.

Comment: Good point.. I used member function type but I still get that error.

Comment: You don't need a member function type declared for a static class method.

Comment: The given typedef above is wrong, pointer to static method SHOULD NOT contain class name - it's unnecessary. I belive error is caused by using undeclared function in assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you posted, it looks to me like you need to declare the class:

```
class CDatabase
{
public:
  static void getDatabaseInteger(DatabaseRow& details);

  //other functions
};
```

before all the arrays that reference the `CDatabase::getDatabaseInteger()` method in **the same header file**. Looks like in your header file you are referencing the static function before you actually declare it. Move this declaration to the beginning of the file.

Comment: thanks.. After moving the class before than the const it worked!